# How to move a spreadsheet into one of another spreadsheet's sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to copy a spreadsheet and paste to a sheet of another spreadsheet my code is:

```
  var open_file = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheets_files.getId());
  var sheet_old = open_file.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  var destination = folder_open.getFilesByName('HistoryGameLog').next();

  var values_old = open_file.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:S50').getValues();

  var destination_sheets = SpreadsheetApp.open(destination);

  //destination_sheets.insertSheet();
  var sheet_new = destination_sheets.getSheetByName('Sheet6').getRange('A1:S50');

  sheet_new.setValue(sheet_old);
```

but when I check the new sheet it show me all "sheet" in the selected range
please help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to manually select range and then set value in destination, you can simply copy the whole sheet in destination, like this :

```
var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SOURCE_ID_GOES HERE');
var sheet = source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('DESTINATION_ID_GOES HERE');
sheet.copyTo(destination);
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet